Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
Encountering this exception while updating Spring Boot and Java versions on multi module project . Here are the details
Previously:
JAVA: 1.8
gradle : 5.6.2-all
springboot : 2.1.1

Current
JAVA: 21
gradle : 8.9
springboot : 3.3.2

Here is the dir structure and build.gradle files
tg-service
---tg-api
  ---build.gradle
---tg-common
  ---build.gradle
---tg-data-access
  ---build.gradle
---build.gradle
---wrapper
----gradle-wrapper.property

here is dependancies
1.build.gradle(tg-api)
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "10.17.3"
}
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'com.map.tg.api'
description = "map tg"
bootJar {
enabled = false
}
dependencies {
implementation project(":tg-common")
implementation project(":tg-data-access")
}

2.build.gradle(tg-common)
plugins {     
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'     
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4' 
  } 
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' 
group = 'com.map.tg.common' 
description = "map tg"



build.gradle(tg-data-access)

plugins {     
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'     
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4' 
} 
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' 
group = 'com.map.tg.data-access' 
description = "map tg"


build.gradle (parent)

subprojects {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
          maven {
             url = "http://devopsartifact.jio.com/artifactory/mvn_all"
             allowInsecureProtocol = true
            }

      }
       apply plugin: "java"
       apply plugin: "jacoco"
   
    java {
        sourceCompatibility = '21'
    }
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    }
    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test
        reports {
            xml.required = true
        }
    }
    build.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.3.2'
        junitVersion = '5.10.0'
        jcpCacheLib = '0.0.2'
        springCloudVersion = '4.1.1'
        swaggerVersion = "3.0.0"
        lombokVersion = "1.18.4"
        jsonVersion = "20230618"
        jakartaValidationVersion = "2.0.1.Final"
        hibernateValidatorVersion = "8.0.1.Final"
        hikariVersion = "3.3.1"
        commonBeanUtilVersion = "1.9.4"
        apacheLang3Version = "3.8.1"
        jasyptVersion = "1.16"
        jacksonDataBindVersion = '2.15.2'
        apacheLang3Version = "3.8.1"
        hibernateEnvVersion = '5.6.15.Final'
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.3.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.3.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.3.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.3.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:3.3.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:3.3.2'
    
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.1.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.1.1'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:4.1.1'
    
        implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:3.2.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:3.2.2'
    
        implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.6.0'
    
        implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.3.2.Final'
        implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:8.0.1.Final'
    
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.1'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.16.1'
    
        implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.13.0'
        implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.13.0'
    
        implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    
        implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0'
        implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4'
        implementation 'org.json:json:20231013'
        implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.1.0'

//        implementation("gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client:flyway-release")
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.3.2.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.12.0'

        implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.15'
        implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.22.1'
        implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.22.1'
    
        implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.2.8'
        implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.21'
        implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:3.0.5'
        implementation 'org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.3'
        implementation 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.10'
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.25.0'
        implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.17.0'

//        runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'

        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.3.2'
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.2'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:5.10.0'
        testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.25.1'
        testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.2.224'
    
       
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui
        implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
        implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
    
        testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0')
        testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0')
        testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.18.3')
    }

}

application.yml
server:   
  port: 8080   
  servlet.context-path: tgservice 
  spring:   
    application:     
         name: service-tg-app   
         profiles:     active: ${PROFILE:sit}`

application-sit.yml
spring:   
  cloud.refresh.enabled: false   
  datasource:     
    url: jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/tgservice_sit     
    username: tgservice     
    password: ********     
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver   
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource   
    flyway:     
      url: jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/tgservice_sit     
      username: tgservice     
      password: ********     
      ignore-missing-migrations: true     
      baseline-on-migrate: true     
      enabled: true     
      locations: classpath:db/migration`

And Here is the full error log
`[ERROR\] \[o.s.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(60)\] - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUserDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ril.dataaccess.tag.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
\[10-09-2024 00:09:45.357\] \[\] \[main\] \[ERROR\] \[org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(859)\] - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
at com.ril.service.tag.Application.main(Application.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:147)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.\<init\>(TomcatWebServer.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:222)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUserDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ril.dataaccess.tag.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.\<init\>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:266)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:240)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4414)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:437)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:128)
... 13 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ril.dataaccess.tag.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)
... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ril.dataaccess.tag.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1705)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1454)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)
... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:682)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource \[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class\]: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: role "pradip.parkar" does not exist
-

SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: role "pradip.parkar" does not exist

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
    ... 94 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: role "pradip.parkar" does not exist
-

SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: role "pradip.parkar" does not exist

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:134)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
    ... 103 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "pradip.parkar" does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2825)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.\<init\>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:175)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.\<init\>(PgConnection.java:263)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:144)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48)
... 109 common frames omitted`

I attempted to resolve the issue by changing the version of the JPA dependency, but I still don’t understand which dependency is causing the error

After two days of thorough analysis, I discovered that the issue was caused by the dependency.
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'

Once I removed this dependency, the project successfully built and started running.
